# List supported date "format codes" for your platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

There is a list of date format codes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Is there a way to get a list of supported format codes for your platform?
I can't find where format codes are located in source code.

Is there a way to do something like?

```
import datetime
datetime.get_supported_format_codes()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) concerning the date format codes:

> The following is a list of all the format codes that the 1989 C standard requires, and these work on *all platforms with a standard C implementation*.

However, some ISO 8601 date values are included, but they're not available on all platforms when used with the `strftime()` method.

If you're going to call an ambiguous or incomplete ISO 8601 parameter, you're going to get a `ValueError`

So, if you want to get the full set of format codes, you'd have to consult the `strftime()` documentation, as supported values for the codes vary across platform, because Python calls the platform C library's `strftime(3)` function.

For Linux see this [page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/strftime.3.en.html). 
For Mac check this [url](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strftime).

As for the code, I'm not aware of any method that does what you want.

Source code for `datetime.py` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py).

Comment: Yeah, cant find it in source code either. Probably cant do that.